# checking the return code using python (MAC)

Tags: python, svn, return-value

I have written a script that checks if an SVN Repo is up and running, the result is based on the return value.

```
import subprocess

url = " validurl"


def check_svn_status():
    subprocess.call(['svn info'+url],shell=True)

def get_status():
    subprocess.call('echo $?',shell=True)



def main():
    check_svn_status()
    get_status()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem I'm facing is that if I change the url to something that does't exist I still get the return value as 0, but if I were to run this outside the script, i.e go to the terminal type `svn info wrong url` and then do a `echo $?` I get a return value of 1. But I can't re-create this in the python. Any guidelines ?

**TraceBack after updating**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "svn_status.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "svn_status.py", line 15, in main
    check_svn_status()
  File "svn_status.py", line 8, in check_svn_status
    p = sp.Popen(['svn info'], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1202, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or director
```

y

Comment: I don't see this code processing any return codes whatsoever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why your approach does not work:**
You invoke two independent subshells. The second shell does not know of the first shell and therefore does not have any information about the returncode of the process that was executed in the first shell.

**Solution:**
Use the `subprocess` module, spawn your subprocess directly (not through a subshell) and retrieve the returncode. Help yourself by reading the documentation of the module: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

There are several ways to achieve your goal. One simple way could be:

```
import subprocess as sp
p = sp.Popen(['command', 'arg1', 'arg2'], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
returncode = p.returncode
```

This way, you don't go through a subshell (`shell=False` by default), which is the recommended approach for various reasons. You directly catch the returncode of the spawned subprocess and you have full access to the subprocess' standard output and standard error.

Comment: I added the following change `p = sp.Popen(['svn info', url, 'echo $?'], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)` and now I'm getting 

`OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`, I used to get this when I didn't have `shell=True`. I updated the question with full Traceback

Comment: 'info' is your first argument and you definitely do not need `'echo $?'` as argument. So try `['svn', 'info', url]` as command.

Answer (score 0):

subprocess.call returns the retcode, just store the result of your `subprocess.call(['svn info'+url],shell=True)`

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html